# C++ macro metaprogramming

Tags: c++, macros

I have the following piece of code:

```
Vec& Vec::operator+=(const double x)
{
    return apply([x](double y) {return x + y;});
}

Vec& Vec::operator-=(const double x)
{
    return apply([x](double y) {return x - y;});
}

Vec& Vec::operator*=(const double x)
{
    return apply([x](double y) {return x * y;});
}

Vec& Vec::operator/=(const double x)
{
    return apply([x](double y) {return x / y;});
}
```

These methods only differ in the operator symbol. Is there a way to simplify writing these methods using a macro?

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: I thought of using something like `#define operate(op) Niz& Niz::operator##op=(const double x) { return apply([x](double y) {return x ##op y;}); }`, but that is not allowed as the character that needs to be replaced is an operator and not a literal.

Comment: No, it isn't allowed because you're using `##` wrong. `##` is used to concatenate macro arguments to form full C++ tokens (such a token being `+=`). You don't just write it in front of every macro argument usage.

Comment: Looks like you operators do the wrong thing: it appears that the `-=` and `/=` operators dont' subtract `x` from each element and divide each element by `x`, but subtract each element from `x` and divide `x` by each element.

Comment: @Walter: That's a good observation. You are right. Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome. Btw, these operators between vectors should be implemented by the like operator for the elements, i.e. `+=` with `+=` not `+`. Moreover, the `/=` is more efficiently implemented as `operator*=(1/x)`: saves `dim-1` divisions (which are more costly than multiplications).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it's rather easy:

```
#define CREATE_OPERATOR(OP) \
  Vec& Vec::operator OP##= (const double x) \
  { return apply([x](double y) { return x OP y; }); }

CREATE_OPERATOR(+)
CREATE_OPERATOR(-)
CREATE_OPERATOR(*)
CREATE_OPERATOR(/)
```

Of course, should you need to re-use this list of operator symbols more than once, you can do it with the [X macro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Macro) trick:

**operators.hxx**

```
OPERATOR(+)
OPERATOR(-)
OPERATOR(*)
OPERATOR(/)

#undef OPERATOR
```

**your code**

```
#define OPERATOR(OP) \
  /* same as above */

#include "operators.hxx"
```

Comment: Ew, `#define` in one file but `#undef` in another?!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I believe X macro is pretty much the only case when this is justifiable.

Answer (score 5):

Seems pretty trivial?

```
#define D(O) \
    Vec& Vec::operator O ## = (const double x) \
    { return apply([x](double y) {return x O y;}); }

D(+)
D(-)
D(*)
D(/)

#undef
```

The `##` "glues" the argument to the `=`, which you need because `+=`, `-=` and so forth are atomic tokens. The rest is all handled by the magic of macros.

#### ([proof that it compiles](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/556bc9f70b773e16))

As an aside, all your operators are wrong; they should read `y O x`, not `x O y`.

Comment: One-letter identifiers for the win.

Comment: @LogicStuff, over zero-length indetifiers, I recon?